# convert svg to png lost fill pattern images

Tags: javascript, c#, svg, export, png

I am generating an svg with dynamically filled images as patterns. When I export this to png, I get a blank svg without any fill images. I have tried javascript as well as c# code.
Javascript  code:

```
var svg = document.querySelector('#element3 svg');

var data1 = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg);

var encodedData = window.btoa(data1);

var data = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + encodedData;
image.src = data;           
$('[id$=objimage]').attr('data', data);
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');          
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.download = "image.png";
a.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

**C# code:**

```
var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input.ImageData);

using (var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
{
    var svgDocument = SvgDocument.Open(stream);
    var bitmap = svgDocument.Draw();
    bitmap.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/Pattern/UserPattern/testimg.png"), ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Can anyone please help in this?

Comment: The images that have in there are linked from external sources? or those are all embedded in?

Comment: You must wait for the image element's onload event to fire before calling context.drawImage.

Comment: @sachin, Images are linked as external sources.

Comment: Here's the svg code:

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="block27" viewBox="0 0 100 100" height="100" width="100" class="ng-scope">

<path d=" M 0 0 L 33 0 L 33 33 L 0 33 Z" fill="#666666" class="pathclass0" style="fill: url('#patternimg1') none;"><img xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" alt="#patternimg1" ng-src="pattern8.png"  />
</path>
</svg>
<pattern id="patternimg1" class="ng-scope" height="100" width="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">

<image height="100" width="100" y="0" x="0" xlink:href="pattern8.png">
</pattern>